# Swift Compiler error: During the test the app in the iphone device

Tags: swift, compiler-errors, frameworks, ios8.1

I want to test my project in an iPhone device, but when I connected my device to system and run the app an error occurs. The error is like that Swift Compiler error:

```
cannot underlie module for 'CoreGraphics'
```

- I am using Xcode 6.1.1 and swift language to develop apps.
- I already provide same Bundle identifier in info. list and where required.
- When I want to add the CoreGraphics framework from the Link frameworks and library option in Project Navigator this will not show this framework in the list.

I don't know where I am going to run..

Comment: Have you tried to import CoreGraphics?

Comment: yes,sir..but after the use of import CoreGraphics in the AppDelegate.swift and ViewController.swift classes same error is occur..

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the Xcode is deleted unfortunately frameworks like UIKIt and CoreGraphics etc..
So i do re-install the Xcode 6.1.1 then these error is fixed...